# Javascript cannot use function argument in one command

Tags: javascript

I have form (in a ColdFusion program -- not that it matters) with two submit buttons (they look quite different from each other) which submits to different programs depending on which button is clicked. The form looks like this:

```
    <form   name       = "pers3aa"
            action     = "" 
            method     = "post" 
            onkeypress = "return event.keyCode != 13;"
            onsubmit   = "return subpers3aa('#coltop#');">
```

Each button calls a Javascript function to set the action  -- they look like this:

```
   <input type   = "Submit"
          name   = "subpers4" 
          class  = "submitbut" 
          value  = "Submit" 
      onclick = "persaasubmit('person4aa.cfm')" >
```

and

```
   <input type   = "Submit"
          id     = "delbut" 
          class  = "onoffbut" 
          value  = "Delete this Value"
      onclick = "persaasubmit('persdel.cfm')">
```

The javascript function persaasubmit is:

```
   function persaasubmit(target) {
   document.pers3aa.action = target;
   }//end function persaasubmit
```

So far, so good -- this works.  However, in another program I have a different form "xrefform", which I submit with a similar function:

```
  function aasubmit(target) {
  document.xrefform.action = target;
  }//end function aasubmit
```

This situation occurs all throughout my system, and the various javascript submit functions are proliferating.  So I tried to combine them by sending the form name as an argument:

```
 function generalsubmit(formname, target) {
  document.formname.action = target;
  }//end function generalsubmit
```

This does not work.  I infer that Javascript cannot find a form called "formname" so it doesn't submit anything.  I'm thinking there probably is syntax for getting Javascript to submit the formname that was passed to it, but I don't know what that might be.  Can anyone help?

Comment: you should try document[formname].action = target instead

Answer (score 1):

In object document there is a 'forms' array. You can access a specific form :

```
document.forms['myform']
```

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track; however, that's not how dot notation works in JavaScript.

**Consider this:**

```
var someVar = "Foo Bar",
    someObject = { someVar: someVar };
//  someObject = {"someVar": "Foo Bar"}

someObject[someVar] == undefined
// Resolves to the 'Foo Bar' property in someObject

someObject.someVar == 'Foo Bar'
// Resolves to the 'someVar' property in someObject

someObject['someVar'] = 'Foo Bar'
// Resolves to t 'someVar' property in someObject
```

**This should work as a drop-in replacement for the function in your question:**

```
function generalsubmit(form, target) {
    form = document.forms[form];
    if (form) {
        form.target = target;  
    }
}
```